# Vk и переключение музыки кнопкой на клавиатуре

Tags: javascript, вконтакте, google-chrome, chrome-extension

На клавиатурах бывает кнопка переключения музыки. Так вот, она работает в VK, и даже если открыть две вкладки с Вконтакте, переключается музыка с обоих. Но если перейти на другой сайт, это уже работать не будет.

Как можно передать это нажатие кнопки с любого другого сайта на вкладку браузера, где открыт сайт VK?
Возможно, это можно сделать с помощью расширения Chrome?

Comment: А я хотел ещё и через веб-сокет сделать, чтобы с телефона управлять)

Comment: Хотели, но не сделали?)

Comment: Да, нет на это времени. Но в списке значится. Когда нибудь сделаю)

Comment: Если не секрет, с помощью чего вы собираетесь управлять на телефоне?
Тоже свою программу писать будете?

Comment: Нет. Просто через веб-сокет по локальной сети. А плагин в браузере тоже сокет слушает и ему и отсылаем команды. Беда только в том, что нужно держать веб-сервер на локальном компьютере. Но он у меня всегда работает.

Comment: @Risto да уж, ответы впечатляют )

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Для перехвата команд понадобится `chrome.commands`, а для работы с вкладками `chrome.tabs`.

---

Подготовим `manifest.json`:

```
"background": {
  "scripts"   : ["command.js"],
  "persistent": false
},

"content_scripts":[  
   {  
      "matches":["*://*.vk.com/*"],
      "js"     :["changeTrack.js"]
   }
],

"permissions":["tabs"],

"commands":{  
   "nextTrack":{  
      "suggested_key":{  
         "default":"MediaNextTrack"
      },
      "description":"nextTrack"
   },
   "prevTrack":{  
      "suggested_key":{  
         "default":"MediaPrevTrack"
      },
      "description":"prevTrack"
   }
}
```

Задача `changeTrack.js` принимать команды, которые будет перехватывать `command.js`.

Командам `nextTrack` и `prevTrack` назначаются клавиши `MediaNextTrack` и `MediaPrevTrack`.

---

### command.js

Для перехвата команд используется событие `chrome.commands.onCommand`.

```
function sendMessage(tabInfo, command) {

    // Получаем вкладку по заданным характеристикам
    chrome.tabs.query(tabInfo, function (tabs) {

        // Если вкладка найдена
        if (tabs.length != 0) {

            // Отправляем ей сообщение
            chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabs[0].id, command);
        }
    });
}

function changeTrack(command) {

    // Если это команды для смены трека
    if (command == "nextTrack" || command == "prevTrack") {

        // Отправляем сообщение вкладке, которая удовлетворяет характеристикам
        sendMessage({url: "*://*.vk.com/*", audible: true}, {command: command});
    }
}

// Перехватываем команды
chrome.commands.onCommand.addListener(changeTrack);
```

Сообщения будут отсылаться только в одну вкладку, потому что в `tabInfo` определен шаблон `url` и свойство `audible`, то есть отправка идет во вкладку, в которой открыта страница VK с проигрывающимся аудио.

Активный аудио источник на странице может быть только один, так как при включении нового, предыдущий ставится на паузу.

---

### changeTrack.js

```
function changeTrack(command) {

    // Ищем элемент на странице, если его нет - плеер не активен. 
    // Источником аудио в таком случае является приложение или видео
    if (!document.getElementsByClassName("fl_l playing")[0]) {

        console.log("Music not playing");

        return;
    }

    // Если плеер активен

    // Выбираем элемент в зависимости от команды и выполняем функцию click
    switch (command) {

        case "nextTrack" : document.getElementsByClassName("next ctrl")[0].click();
            break;
        case "prevTrack" : document.getElementsByClassName("prev ctrl")[0].click();
            break;
    }
}


chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function (request, sender, sendResponse) {

    // Если получена команда для смены трека
    if (request.command) {

        changeTrack(request.command);
    }
});
```

Под элементами подразумеваются кнопки плеера, т.е `DOM` элементы.

Воспроизведение/пауза - `div` с изменяющимся классом. Когда идет воспроизведение установлен класс `fl_l playing`.

---

[chrome.commands](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/commands) | [chrome.tabs](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs) | [Message Passing](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging)